# Why can not a verb of "To gulp the glass of water with such thirst" be seen?

Tags: grammar

I can not see a verb of "To gulp the glass of water with such thirst" 
in the following sentence (Source: http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/phrase.pdf). What does the sentence mean?

> **To gulp the glass of water with such thirst** that streams of liquid ran down his chin and wet the front of his already sweat soaked shirt.

How is the sentence reconstructed to have a subject and a verb?

Does it mean "Somebody gulp the glass of water with such thirst that streams of liquid ran down his chin and wet the front of his already sweat soaked shirt" ?

What grammars do I need to learn in order to learn how to express sentences like this without the verbs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't a sentence. The source you have gives it as an example of an infinitive phrase. It is an example of a particularly long and complex infinitive phrase.

The verb is "to gulp" but there is no finite verb. The whole phrase functions rather like a noun.  Such long phrases need to be handled carefully, as the listener (and speaker) can get lost.

You could make it into a sentence by simply changing it to

> He gulped the glass...

I.e giving it a subject and making the verb finite.  I've used past tense, but other tenses are possible.  Making it into a sentence changes the meaning.

You can also use this infinitive phrase in a sentence

> He wanted to gulp the glass of water...

There are lots of uses of infinitive phrases in English.